# How to make a six sided star using turtle, with different sizes for the triangles? This is what I got, not sure , can someone help me?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.speed(30)


def triangle(sz):
    for i in range(3):
        tess.fd(sz)
        tess.lt(120)

def sixPtdStar(sz):
    triangle(sz)
    tess.lt(90)
    tess.pu()
    tess.fd(80)
    tess.rt(90)
    tess.fd(120)
    tess.pd()
    tess.rt(180)
    triangle(sz)
```

As requested in the title the question is: How do I make a six sided star using turtle, with different sizes for the triangles?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Format your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you're drawing your first triangle with the turtle at one vertex.  Drawing this triangle is simple but then you're at a loss where to start drawing the next triangle.  In this situation, I'd change my design to draw the triangle centered on the turtle.  Then, drawing the second triangle is simply a matter of starting over again after rotating the turtle slightly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def triangle(side):
    tess.pendown()

    for _ in range(3):
        tess.forward(side)
        tess.left(120)

    tess.penup()

def sixPtdStar(side):
    height = side * 3**0.5 / 2  # equilateral triangle

    for _ in range(2):
        tess.right(30)
        tess.forward(2 * height / 3)
        tess.left(90 + 60)
        triangle(side)
        tess.right(90 + 60)
        tess.backward(2 * height / 3)
        tess.right(30)

tess = Turtle()
tess.penup()
tess.dot()  # mark the center of our star

sixPtdStar(100)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Whenever I try to draw a centered figure, I use `tess.dot()` as a debugging aid to know where that center is so I can visually check that I'm doing it right:

[image]

An alternative approach, that still puts the turtle at the center of the figure, is to push the centering work into `triangle()` and keeping `sixPtdStar()` simple.  One way to do this is use turtle's own `circle()` function to draw our triangles:

```
def triangle(side):
    height = side * 3**0.5 / 2  # equilateral triangle
    radius = 2 * height / 3

    # center the circle on tess' position
    tess.right(90)
    tess.forward(radius)
    tess.left(90)

    tess.pendown()
    tess.circle(radius, steps=3)
    tess.penup()

    # return tess to where she started
    tess.left(90)
    tess.forward(radius)
    tess.right(90)

def sixPtdStar(side):
     triangle(side)
     tess.right(60)
     triangle(side)
```

If we focus on using `circle()` to draw our triangles, and don't care about centering it on the turtle's current position, we can simply do:

```
def triangle(radius):
    tess.pendown()
    tess.circle(radius, steps=3)
    tess.penup()

def sixPtdStar(side):
    radius = side * 3**0.5 / 3  # equilateral triangle
    triangle(radius)
    tess.circle(radius, extent=60)
    triangle(radius)
```

Keeping `triangle()` the same as above, we change change `sixPtdStar()` from drawing two *overlapping* triangles to instead drawing six triangles in a circle:

```
def sixPtdStar(side):
    radius = side * 3**0.5 / 3  # equilateral triangle

    for _ in range(6):
        triangle(radius / 3)
        tess.circle(radius, extent=60)
```

Or if we want a paricularly elegant star, change `radius / 3` to `radius / 2` to get:

[image]